# Retrieving question from database and display it in radio button

Tags: laravel

I have a  questions table, I managed to create a form  and send the data to database,  i need a user to answer the question by selecting the best answer from radio button list, i have retrieved the question from a database but the radio button does not work correct, when i select the answer from the first question and the when a go to second question the first question radio button is unchecked, i have attached my code. Please anyone who can help me

```
              my view code
                <h2>Welcome to Online Teacher Verification Test:</h2>

                @foreach($qns as $qn)

                {{$qn->question_name}}
               <div class="form-check">
               <label class="form-check-label" for="opt1">
               <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="opt1" 
               name="opt" value="opt1">{{$qn->opt1}}
                </label>
               </div>
               <div class="form-check">
               <label class="form-check-label" for="opt2">
                <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="opt2" 
                name="opt" value="opt2">{{$qn->opt2}}
                 </label>
                 </div>
                 <div class="form-check">
               <label class="form-check-label" for="opt3">
               <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="opt3" 
                 name="opt" value="opt3">{{$qn->opt3}}
                 </label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check">
                 <label class="form-check-label" for="opt4">
                 <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="opt4" 
                 name="opt" value="opt4">{{$qn->opt4}}
                 </label>
                  </div>

                 @endforeach

                  my controller code
                    use App\Topics;
                    use App\Questions;

                    class QuestionController extends Controller
                     {
                          /**
                       * Display a listing of the resource.
                        *
                          * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
                               */
                          public function index()
                        {

                       $qns= Questions::all();
                       return view('test.index')->with('qns',$qns);

                       }
```

I need when a user answer a question by selecting an answer from button, when he/she moves to the second question the first question should remain checked

Comment: you gave them all the same name, they need their own groups

Comment: How do i group it Thomas can you please show me some code, thank you

Comment: Names per question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well all the radio buttons have the same name when dom renders. So if you check the first one and then the second, the first one becomes unchecked. Try something like

```
@foreach($qns as $qn)
{{$qn->question_name}}
<div class="form-check">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="opt1">
    <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="opt1" 
               name="opt{{ $qn->id }}" value="opt1">{{$qn->opt1}}
    </label>
</div>
<div class="form-check">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="opt2">
    <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="opt2" 
                name="opt{{ $qn->id }}" value="opt2">{{$qn->opt2}}
    </label>
</div>
<div class="form-check">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="opt3">
    <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="opt3" 
                 name="opt{{ $qn->id }}" value="opt3">{{$qn->opt3}}
    </label>
</div>
<div class="form-check">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="opt4">
    <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="opt4" 
                 name="opt{{ $qn->id }}" value="opt4">{{$qn->opt4}}
    </label>
</div>
@endforeach
```

This way you will get different name for each questions and you can check for each question. Well now if you want save them to database you can access the answers in controller with different names try like

```
public function saveAnswers(Request $request)
{
    $questions = Questions::all();
    foreach($questions as $qns){
        $name = "opt".$qns->id;
        $answer = $request->$name;
        //here you can save or anything you want to do
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set name of radio button like `name="qn{{ $qn->id }}"` so that it is unique.